# output of sklearn lda.predict are different labels than input labels

Tags: python, scikit-learn, predict, confusion-matrix

I want to classify three different activities so I have three labels 20,30,40 and when I look into the confusion matrix I get 9 rows and columns and labels which were not in the input vector like 26,27,28.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

```
trL, testL,trE,testE,= train_test_split(yset, Esetnew,test_size=0.2, shuffle=False) 


clfLinE = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
clfLinE.fit(trE,trL)

predLabLinE = clfLinE.predict(testE)
confLinE=confusion_matrix(testL,predLabLinE)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add some sample of Your input and output of the algorithm, so that one could reproduce it.

Comment: Check unique values in `yset`